# Adding row to matrix in if statement MATLAB

Tags: matlab, if-statement, for-loop, matrix, iteration

I have a code that should do exactly this:

```
A = [2;3;4;5;6;7];
b = 2;
B(10).b = zeros(6,1);

for i = 1:10
    C = A;
    B(i).b = C.*(b^i);
    if i>1
        if B(i).b(1,1)-B(i-1).b(1,1)>50
            C(7) = b;
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is that in every iteration C matrix is replaced with the values in matrix A. This is simplified version of my code, but the essence is here, and the code should do exactly this, at some point if a criteria is met, add another row to matrix C and continue executing the code with that row in matrix C. Is it possible to do that? I'd appreciate ideas very much. Thank you.

Comment: I don't get what you mean, please explain more,

Comment: Starting point is C matrix, it is the matrix on which the calculations are done. After some calculations are done it is being compared if criteria is met. If that statement is true, a row to the C matrix is added. The problem is that, in this code, because of the line C = A, after the row is added and another iteration starts, that same row is deleted as starting value of C matrix is loaded. I need to be able to add row to matrix C and continue executing calculations with that added row. I hope it's clearer now,  @Rashid

Comment: So why don't you set `C=A` outside the loop, before the first `for`, wouldn't it solve the problem?

Comment: because it is needed for the calculations to be done on that matrix, and it (C matrix) is changeable in full code, so after every iteration is done and `if`statement is not true, the value of C matrix must be returned to starting point

Comment: okey, that makes sense, would `C(1:6) = A` help? because it seems that both `A` and `C` are vectors,

Comment: that is very much helpful, thank you @Rashid

Answer (score 1):

You can append b to C and overwrite the value of C with the newly created value:

```
if i>1
    if B(i).b(1,1)-B(i-1).b(1,1)>50
        C = [C; b];
    end
end
```

This should work just fine as long as C & b are not too large.

Comment: Thank you for answer, @Rashid s answer helped me with this problem. But since it's a comment i couldn't accept it as a valid and mark as solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to change the matrix size during execution because you loose runtime. The best solution is to estimate the size of the matrix at the very beginning.

If there is no other possibility, you can add a row by the following code:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
A = vertcat(A,[2 3]);
```

The same works also for columns:

```
A = [1 2; 3 4];
A = horzcat(A,[2; 3]);
```

To take away a row, just write (here for row 2):

```
A(2,:) = [];
```

The same works with columns:

```
A(:,2) = [];
```

To change only selective parts of a matrix, the following can be done (some examples):

```
A(1:2,1) = [2 3]; % change row
A(1,1:2) = [2;3]; % change column
A(2,1) = 5; % change single cell
```

This is exactly what Rashid does with the statement C(1:6) = A;. Because it is only a column vector, the indices refer to the columns. It is equivalent to C(1,1:6)=A;

Then it is only a question of implementation to put around an if-statement with your desired condition.

Best regards

Comment: thank you @Sebastian for your reply. It is not possible to estimate the size of the matrix as it depends on the result of the calculations, which are not predictable. As for the recursive function, i don't understand how can it be implemented to avoid code line C = A to delete added row.

Comment: @Drazen: I changed my response. It was not really clear at the beginning what you really want. I understood that you want to know how to add a row to a matrix. Therefore, I wrote some independent examples to show you how to add a row. Now it contains also the solution from Rashid. So basically you can close the thread. Recursive functions are of course not necessary in your case.